# Fill down if no value in period, autoknow the periods

Tags: sql-server, query

I have created a query that gets the running total from my general ledger by period. This works fine, however as soon as there are no transasctions in a period, my query will return noting in that period. I would like to add previous value if this is the case. I have tried joining with my dimension period table, but have not been succesful.

Example:
Project 12345
GL:

| project | amount | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10 | 202001 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202002 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202003 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202004 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202005 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202006 |

My code is the following:

```
 select project, Period,
 Sum( Sum (amount))
 over (
 partition by project
 order by Period
 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS [RTamt]
from GL.table
group by project, period
```

This would return the following table

| project | amount | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10 | 202001 |
| 12345 | 20 | 202002 |
| 12345 | 30 | 202003 |
| 12345 | 40 | 202004 |
| 12345 | 50 | 202005 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202006 |

I would like it to continue until today period like this:

| project | amount | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10 | 202001 |
| 12345 | 20 | 202002 |
| 12345 | 30 | 202003 |
| 12345 | 40 | 202004 |
| 12345 | 50 | 202005 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202006 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202007 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202008 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202009 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202010 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202011 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202012 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202101 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202102 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202103 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202104 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202105 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202106 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202107 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202108 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202109 |

Is there an easy way to do this by joining a period table maybe?

Thanks so much!

Comment: it sure can be a data. right not its INT. If making this a date instead (i.e first in every month, then that is perfectly fine). @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive CTE based on the highest period for any given project, then use a union to piece those two sets together. There is probably a slightly cleaner way to do this but I wanted to do as little to your existing query as possible (I just added a row number and slight formatting changes for my own readability).

```
DECLARE @d date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1);

;WITH src AS -- mostly your existing query
(
  SELECT project, 
         period,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
              (PARTITION BY project ORDER BY period DESC),
         amount = SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER 
                  (PARTITION BY project ORDER BY period
                   ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  FROM dbo.GLProject
  GROUP BY project, period
),
recur AS
(
  SELECT project, period = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, period), amount
  FROM src 
  WHERE rn = 1 AND period < @d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT project, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, period), amount
  FROM recur WHERE period < @d 
)
SELECT project, amount, period = CONVERT(char(6), period, 112)
FROM src
UNION ALL
SELECT project, amount, period = CONVERT(char(6), period, 112)
FROM recur
ORDER BY project, period;
```

[Working db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a06de23b3df1a705ee47ab86b4b83f6b)

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: After further review it looks like the code is missing periods in between and just filling out from last transaction. For instance if I where to add another row for project 12345 with period 202009 from my original question, it would miss the periods in between (202007 and 202008). Any easy fix regarding this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I'll create a new post now!

Comment: Tried to do that now. Hope I made it easy for people to understand my question. Thank you so much for your help!